# Python Queue used in Threading - Order Preserving?

Tags: python, multithreading

This is not about execution order - it is about the order in which output is stored in queues in python.

Basic question -

I have 10 threads applying a function to a queue of arguments and results are in another queue. Is it guaranteed that the order of the arguments and the results in the two queues will be identical? My code seems to suggest so .`

```
import Queue
import threading
import time
import random

print_lock = threading.Lock() 
r = random.Random()
r.seed=5

def calc(num_q, q):  

    while True:

        number = num_q.get()

        with print_lock:
            print(threading.current_thread().name,number)  
        #print(number)
        q.put(number)
        time.sleep(r.randint(0,5))
        num_q.task_done()
        q.task_done()

#threads=[]

numbers =[z for z in range(20)]

num_q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)

num_threads = 10

for x in range(num_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=calc, args=(num_q,q))
    t.daemon= True
    #threads.append(t)
    t.start()

start = time.time()  
for n in numbers:
    num_q.put(n)

num_q.join()
print('Entire job took:',time.time() - start)
while q.empty() is False:
    print(q.get())`
```

Comment: Not quite - that does not discuss queues and is abut java.

Comment: Threads are run *concurrently*. So there is no guarantee for the order of the result put in the queue is even when arguments to the function are taken from a queue. You can try to run your code with a small example to test this.

Comment: OK - but my code seems to preserve order.

Comment: You use `Lock` therefore execution of `read - write` is serialized and this preserve Order. The disadvantage is, you are loosing **concurrently** running your Thread's.

Comment: Nice - thanks - please post in answer so I can accept